# How to convert a List of Map that has object as key to Map?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a repository query that is returning a list of Maps as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT new map(key(m), value(m) ) from User u join u.shopRoleMap m where u.usEmail = :email")
     List<Map<Shop,Role>> findByUserEmail(String email);
```

The Mapping on User is as follows:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_shop_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_fk"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_fk"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "shop_fk")
    private Map<Shop, Role> shopRoleMap = new HashMap<>();
```

On my service I need to get the map as `Map<Shop,Role>` so that I can get the keys and values correspondingly. The code is as follows:

```
List<Map<Shop,Role>> shopRole= userRepository.findByUserEmail(email);

        for (Map<Shop,Role> map : shopRole){
            for (Map.Entry<Shop,Role> result : map.entrySet()){
                System.out.println("The key is: "+result.getKey());
                System.out.println("And the value is: "+result.getValue());
            }
        }
        }
```

The result that I get is somewhat bizarre, as I expected `result.getKey()` would give me `Shop` as the key. However, I'm getting keys as 0's and 1's.

```
The key is: 0
And the value is: Shop{id=54, sh_name='Frefdv', sh_icon='icon url', sh_description='Fashion Shop', sh_tag='metadata', uuid='99dba3d5-dfaa-446d-9649-b9b98f422f87', sh_enabled='N', created_at=2020-07-30T15:54:10, updated_at=2020-07-30T15:54:10, created_by='e0b009ef-27c2-405b-961a-86f199b15167', updated_by='e0b009ef-27c2-405b-961a-86f199b15167'}
The key is: 1
And the value is: Role{id=0, roleName='ADMIN'}
The key is: 0
And the value is: Shop{id=55, sh_name='fnhfh', sh_icon='icon url', sh_description='Fashion Shop', sh_tag='metadata', uuid='e3ccdbdf-aad2-43ba-8331-91b2c2c01853', sh_enabled='N', created_at=2020-07-30T15:54:23, updated_at=2020-07-30T15:54:23, created_by='e0b009ef-27c2-405b-961a-86f199b15167', updated_by='e0b009ef-27c2-405b-961a-86f199b15167'}
The key is: 1
And the value is: Role{id=0, roleName='ADMIN'}
```

How can I convert this `List<Map<Shop,Role>>` to a map where I can get key value pairs?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. But it is getting flagged because it has 3 questions and for the post to be focused, just leave one question and is one of the guidelines. And also java stream cannot do anything here if jpa returns string so worth removing it.

Comment: Your nested for loop and the stream are fine if your shopRole is actually a List<Map<Shop, Role>>. Judging by your output and error I think it's safe to assume shopRole is actually something else. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with JPA/HQL to help you here, but I would suggest you use a debugger to see what you actually get and work from there.

Comment: @Rick it's sad that the deduced map key is not of type Shop. Don't know where the code is getting messed up.

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai thank you for the shout. i have edited to leave the question studious.

Comment: Can you share the relevant jpa annotations on `User` & `shopRoleMap`

Comment: @PrasadU added the jpa annotation that does the mapping for entities Shop and Role.

Answer (score 1):

The HQL in question is actually returning **List<Map<String, Object>>**

```
SELECT new map(key(m), value(m) ) from User u join u.shopRoleMap m where u.usEmail = :email
```

The syntax for **new map** basically expects the Values. So when key(m) and value(m) is passed to it, then the key(m) as well as value(m) are treated as Map values. The key to the map is basically the index value (0,1,2,..)

You can read more about it in the Hibernate Documentation -
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause

[image]

So, you should be replacing your HQL to

```
SELECT entry(m) from User u join u.shopRoleMap m where u.usEmail = :email
```

This should return **List<Map.Entry<Shop,Role>>** which can be iterated to obtain the correct results.